# How to remove entire tr when a keyword is contained within a specific td

Tags: javascript, jquery

Inside a number of `<tr>`'s in my document there are 7  classes, each one sometimes has a corresponding class name (i.e. sub, id, assigned, sub, sub, status, and one classless "td").  Within the td class = "status" lies a span class defined as  either 
`<span class = "statusBox">Passed</span>`
or 
`<span class = "statusBox">Failed</span>.`

If the text contained within the span class is "Passed", I need to delete the entire `<tr>`.  If it's failed it stays on the document.  How can I achieve this?

My first attempt was through a call such as:

```
function() {
    if ($('tr td span.statusBox').html() == "Passed"){
    $('tr td span.statusBox').hide();  
}
```

But this removed every instance of only the phrase "Passed", not the entire `<tr>`.

I've also tried 
   `$("tr td span.statusBox:contains('Passed')").each(function(){
    $(this).css("visibility","hidden");
    });`

I feel like this is more along the right path, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were close: find the status box with the word 'Passed' and then find the closest ancestor `tr` element and remove it from the DOM:

```
$("tr td span.statusBox").filter(":contains('Passed')").each(function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Since the `:contains` operator is a jQuery extension (it has been deprecated from the CSS spec), it's faster to break the selector into two parts. The first is finding all spans of class `statusBox`, this will look up the elements using native browser methods. Then those elements are filtered using the `:contains` operator (which may have a native implementation or may be implemented in jQuery, depending on the browser).

Comment: I can't upvote because I'm a new user but I just wanted to let you know it worked fantastically.  Thanks.

Comment: @Fields Glad to help :) And welcome to StackOverflow! Don't worry about the upvote, but since this answer helped you, would you mind accepting it as correct? That way other people who have a similar question will know this is the answer :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are altering the visibility of the span instead of the parent `<tr>`. You can use `$(this).closest('tr')` to get to the row element and then alter its visibility.

```
$("tr td span.statusBox:contains('Passed')").each(function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').css("visibility","hidden"); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".statusBox").each(function (i, e) {
    if ($(e).text() == "Passed") {
        $(e).closest('tr').hide();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/B7Wqy/